# OpenCart custom page not accessible

Tags: php, opencart

I have a custom page in the backend (admin) of my OpenCart site. It is an exact copy of admin/view/template/sale/order_info.tpl but with a few minor cosmetic changes. It is located at admin/view/template/sale/order_preview.tpl. I have also created a copy of admin/controller/sale/order.php, and called it admin/controller/sale/order_preview.php, and modified the first line so that it reads:

```
class ControllerSaleOrderPreview extends Controller {
```

but when I try to access the page at the url "http://www.example.com/admin/index.php?route=sale/order/preview&token=BtkiB5js5u3hkXBYrFlGgz39dWtrQ4Ww&order_id=2" I get "Page Not Found!" every time.

What else do I need in order to be able to access this page? This is in OpenCart 2.3.0.2.

Comment: More than likely there is a route file that needs to be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url is wrong based on how you created the page.

`route=sale/order/preview`

This will call the function `preview` in your `sale/order` controller.  Since you created a new controller for your changes, the route is going to be different. Change the route to match the new controller.

`route=sale/order_preview`

The thing to keep in mind is the route parameter is all about pointing you at a controller, so it is the controller filename you want to pay attention to.  Opencart uses the convention of `route=folder/controllerFilename/methodToCall` If you omit the third part  `route=folder/controllerFilename`, index is the default method called.

Comment: I thought that OpenCart turned underscores in these file names into slashes... so when I copied order_info.tpl and turned it into order_preview.tpl, I thought that a "route=sale/order/preview" would be handed correctly the same way that the "route=sale/order/info" URL is handled.

Comment: Update - I was mistaken about the underscores in this case, when I tried it with your suggestion of

    route=sale/order_preview

it appears to behave much more as expected. Thank you!